# Merge detached JPA entity with @version field

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA entity class with a @Version field for optimistic locking. I need to `merge()` a detached entity instance that has its version field uninitialized over an existing entity instance in the persistence context. When doing this the managed instance has its version field overwritten which leads to an OptimisticLockException later on.

I could manually copy contents of the version field from the managed to the detached entity before merging but I find this a bit awkward. Is there a better option or best practice to handle this scenario?

Comment: Why would the version field be uninitialized? Was this entity you are trying to merge was previously loaded from the DB, prior to detachment? Is so, the version field should have been set during retrieval.

Comment: The detached entity is not read from the database but is built from data from an external CSV file. The data in this file should be used to batch update the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

Doing merge is not going to work if you have the version field uninitialized. It has to be there. The JPA provider will have to compare the version field of the entity you are trying to merge with the version that is in the database. If entity version is older than what is in the database, then it will have to throw an exception.

What you can do instead of doing a merge, is to use update via JPA query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("UPDATE MyEntity me SET me.versionField = me.versionField + 1....");
q.executeUpdate();
```

You can set the other fields of your entity in this query, but what's important is you have to explicitly increment the value of the version field. The version field is not automatically incremented on updates via query.

Comment: The entity in question has other associated entities and quite a lot of fields to merge. I dont want to do this manually but let the entitymanager do the merging. Without version field this was quite easy:

Comment: Is it possible to store the version value to the CSV file as well? So that when you construct your entities, the version field will be initialized.

Comment: Creating the detached entity from csv data, then merge() the whole object graph. With version field I have to find() the root entity into the persistence context, then merge the versions from the managed into the detached object graph then merge(). So far the easiest solution for me, but it still seems quite ugly.

Comment: The csv file is created by an external provider, so i dont have a version number when creating the detached entities.

Comment: Is the entity expected to be updated concurrently by multiple processes or threads? If not you may not need optimistic locking, then you can get rid of the version field. If that is not an option, then you are only left with querying the entity's version before doing a merge.

Comment: Thats not an option unfortunately, there are other users accessing the database, possibly modifying data.